# Using Intellij Structural Search and Replace to change declaration types

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

Any IDE wizards hanging out?

I want to do something seemingly simple, which is turning out to be fairly difficult: I want to replace all variable declarations of one type with variable declarations of another type

Ex:

```
Foo x; ==> Bar x;
protected final Foo x; ==> protected final Bar x;
public abstract Foo = Foo() + 7; ==> public abstract Bar = Foo() + 7;
```

I figure that this must be possible but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how. I can get close, but I stall on the following issues:

1. How can I either not modify the "modifiers" like `public`, `final`, and so on, preceding the `Foo` variable declaration, or capture them so that I can make sure they don't get lost?
2. How can I *not* replace the right-hand side of the equals sign in the 3rd example?

Comment: Are you committed to using Structural Search and Replace, or would you consider a regex-based solution?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: Doesn't Type migration refactoring do the job?

Comment: @Argb32 No, alas, it doesn't. That would work if I needed to refactor a particular method, or a particular variable. Unfortunately, I need to refactor _every instance of Foo in an enormous project._ (In case you're interested why, the reason is that I have to replace every instance of Foo with an instance of Bar -- a superclass of Foo, and then cast Bar to Foo every time Foo is used. In case you're interested why... you couldn't be. This is a hell of Java refactoring :) ).

Comment: @HankD, I'm not. I'd do whatever worked.

Comment: Is there some relationship between Foo and Bar? Like splitting an interface or abstract class from an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Structural Search & Replace should work.

Search Pattern:

```
Foo $a$ = $b$;
```

Replacement Pattern:

```
Bar $a$ = $b$;
```

Click `Edit Variables` and set the `Minimum count` of `b` to 0 and `Maximum count` to `1`. Modifiers should get saved automatically.